# Angular 2 passing object to component

Tags: input, typescript, angular

I'm trying to pass an object to another component.

Request-list.html

```
<tr [routerLink]="['Request', { id: request.id }]" *ngFor="let request of requests" [req]="request">
                        <td class=" ">{{ request.datum }}</td>
                        <td class=" ">{{ request.artist.name }} </td>
                        <td class=" ">{{ request.artist.user.first_name }}
                        <td class=" ">{{ request.user.first_name }}</td>
                        <td class=" ">{{ request.duration.price }}</td>
                        <td class=" ">{{ request.created_at }}</td>
                        <td class=" ">{{ request.rejected_at }}</td>
                    </tr>
```

RequestListComponent

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Service} from './../services/service.service';
import {Request} from './../classes/request';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {RequestComponent} from './request.component';

@Component({
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RequestComponent],
  templateUrl: 'partials/request-list.html'
})

export class RequestListComponent {
  requests: Request[];
  constructor(private _Service: Service) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this._Service.getRequests().subscribe(data => this.requests = data);
  }
}
```

RequestComponent

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Service} from './../services/service.service';
import {Request} from './../classes/request';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'partials/request.html'
})

export class RequestComponent {
  @Input() req: Request;

  constructor(private _Service: Service) {}
}
```

However I get the error: "Can't bind to 'req' since it isn't a known native property"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the selector of you `RequestComponent`?

Comment: The problem is, that the `RequestComponent` is loaded with the router and not inside the `RequestListComponent`. Because of this, you can not use the `@Input()` to pass data into the `RequestComponent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you cannot use `@Input()` if your `RequestComponent` is loaded with the `Router`. Unfortunately it is not possible to pass `RouteData` with the `RouteLink`-Directive.

To solve this problem, I would load the `Request` inside the `RequestComponent` from the service, which you used to load the list of `Requests`. To reduce the traffic to a backend, if you have one, you can build some caching mechanism.

```
export class RequestComponent {
    req: Request;

    constructor(private _Service: Service, routeParams : RouteParams) {
        this.req = _Service.getRequestById(routeParams.get('id'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Will look into this. There already is a service that handles http requests with the backend. Should I use that one, or is it a best practice to create a new service for requests?

Comment: @Ruben This depends on your service, difficult to say without the code.

Comment: Ok, yeah I implemented it in the service we have for know. Working together with someone else and we will discuss it what would be best for us.